# Trouble comprehending a sentence with ~ように

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

Im currently studying with Tobira. I'm in chapter 1 right now and in the grammar section, it defines ように as being used when:

1. X resembles Y
2. When X is as Y shows, says, explains, etc.
3. When X does something as shown/said/explained/etc. in/by Y

One of the examples sentence written in this section, and the one I'm having trouble trying to figure out how it relates to the functions written above is:

この写真を見れば分かるように、ロンドンには、色々な名所がある。

I understood this as: 
"If you look at this photo, you'll know that there are various famous places in London."

This was my best guess as to what the sentence means because I don't know how ように factors into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ように like "**as** ～" (your second or third definition). Try reading it like this:

> この写真を見れば分かる**ように**、
>   **As** you can understand if you look at this photo,
>
> ロンドンには、色々な名所がある。
>   there are various famous places in London.

Or more naturally, the first half of the sentence means "As shown in the photo, ..."